# ImageMagick Crop image keeping original position

Tags: imagemagick

Having [image]
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/10/Stratton_Oakmont_logo.svg/1200px-Stratton_Oakmont_logo.svg.png

I would like to cut the lion but keep the original image size and lion in place.

right now i'm only able to cut the lion and keep the original image size, but not it's position:

```
convert /tmp/stratton.png -crop 550x800+320+30 -background none  -extent 1200x1920 /tmp/output.png
```

[image]

How can i keep the lion in it's original position?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by snibgo in ImageMagick official forums:

```
convert 1200px-Stratton_Oakmont_logo_svg.png -crop 550x800+320+30 -background Blue -layers Flatten x.png
```